# Java Spring MVC logging

Tags: logging, model-view-controller

Recently I have joined to a team which develops quite huge Java projects. It's a classical Spring MVC application (controllers which returns jsp views, Services classes, facades etc..). The problem is that logging is quite poor: application intercepts soap and rest requests and prints it). It leads to problems during bug analysis. It's hard to discover which which SOAP/REST requests belongs to executed action beacuse on INT environment testers perform a lot of tests. My question is: how to improbe logging in such app ? What are good practices ? What can I make now ? Should we for example create aspectj pointcuts for all *Service, *Controller and *Facade classes ? In result I would like to recive logs in readable format where I can easily track execution path from controller input to controller output.

Comment: try saving all services request and response in DB, let all remaining logs as it is.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve logs when every action on controller has unique id which is propagated to all function executed from controller ? Lets suppose that two users execute function foo() at one moment, function foo() calls function a(), function a() calls b() and in logs will be: logg: foo() id=1, foo() id=2, logg: a(), id =1, log: b() id= 1,...

Answer (score 0):

Add logerrs at entry and exit of every function.

Logging should contain important information like:

```
ClassName - methodName - for some unique Id(userId/sessionId) starts/end.
```

Recommended to use log.debug() for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a logging framework with a "mapped diagnostic context" (logback) or "nested diagnostic context" (log4j2).
Such diagnostic contexts are key-value stores that provide values the logger can print.

Make sure the relevant context information is in the diagnostic context; in Spring MVC, you'd add a filter that inspects the request and pulls out whatever information is of interest - request id, user name associated with session id, whatever.
Extra points if the filter removes that information on processing exit - if you have thread pools, the DC will spill over into processing for the next request and that would be a permanent source of confusion.

Format the log messages using the MDC data.
(With a logging framework, this is already a simple format escape code.)

If you don't use a logging framework, introduce that first.
You'll get a lot of advantages:

- Every message can get a log level. You can configure which classes are logged at what level, so developers can freely add tons of log messages wherever they please, if they are at DEBUG level they will be ignored (the ignore-this logic still takes a little bit of CPU, but not much - the expensive concatenate-the-strings-to-a-message operations are skipped).
- Log levels are configured in application.yaml.
- Log levels can be changed at runtime - there's an actuator endpoint for that, so you can crank up logging even in production to diagnose those things that don't show up in testing. Just reduce the log level back after you have results, to prevent your logs from overflowing.